# How to generate the food for a snake game

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I can not figure out how to generate the food for the snake to eat. I know the position of the snake at line 97 and 98, I have created a class to generate a pixel where I want to draw a peace of food at line 22 (EDIT: should probably be a function, commented #def (?) in the code). All I have to do is add 15 pixels at the x and y coordinates from the position that is randomly allocated and print it to get a block.

The problem is to check if I eat it or not. It should be something like:

```
if x >= x_food && x <= x_food + 15 || y >= y_food && y <= y_food + 15:
    ...add a point and make snake longer...
```

The problem is putting it all together for some reason.. Can some one give me a hint or solve how I should write this class so I can continue with other problems? Thank you!

```
import pygame
import random

#Global variables
#Color
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

#Start length of snake
snake_length = 3

#Set the width of the segments of the snake
segment_width = 15
segment_height = 15
# Margin within each segment
segment_margin = 3

#Set initial speed
x_change = segment_width + segment_margin
y_change = 0

#def (?)
class Food():
    #Class to print food
    x_food = random.randint(0, 785)
    y_food = random.randint(0, 585)


class Segment(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ Class to represent the segment of the snake. """
    # Methods
    # Constructer function
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        #Call the parents constructor
        super().__init__()

        #Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([segment_width, segment_height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)

        #Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

#Call this function so the Pygame library can initialize itself
pygame.init()

#Create an 800x600 size screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])

#Set the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

allspriteslist = pygame.sprite.Group()

#Create an initial snake
snake_segments = []
for i in range(snake_length):
    x = 250 - (segment_width + segment_margin) * i
    y = 30
    segment = Segment(x, y)
    snake_segments.append(segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        #Set the speed based on the key pressed
        #We want the speed to be enough that we move a full
        #Segment, plus the margin
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = (segment_width + segment_margin) * -1
                y_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = (segment_width + segment_margin)
                y_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                x_change = 0
                y_change = (segment_height + segment_margin) * -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                x_change = 0
                y_change = (segment_width + segment_margin)

    #Get rid of last segment of the snake
    #.pop() command removes last item in list
    old_segment = snake_segments.pop()
    allspriteslist.remove(old_segment)

    #Figure out where new segment will be
    x = snake_segments[0].rect.x + x_change
    y = snake_segments[0].rect.y + y_change
    segment = Segment(x, y)

    #Insert new segment to the list
    snake_segments.insert(0, segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

    #Draw
    #Clear screen
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    allspriteslist.draw(screen)

    #Flip screen
    pygame.display.flip()

    #Pause
    clock.tick(5)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: if you are interested Salviati, ive got a pygame snake, i can send you the code if you would like it and you can maybe get a few tips from it, the code is actuely 3 programs, 1 for the snake, 1 for the food and 1 for putting it all together,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i took your code and i think i work something out, pls note that this only monitors when the snake goes over the block, then it prints: yummy, so you will have to add the detail, also note that i dont use your class to generate the food:

```
import pygame
import random

#Global variables
#Color
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

#Start length of snake
snake_length = 3

#Set the width of the segments of the snake
segment_width = 15
segment_height = 15
# Margin within each segment
segment_margin = 3

#Set initial speed
x_change = segment_width + segment_margin
y_change = 0

#def (?)
class Food():
    #Class to print food
    x_food = random.randint(0, 785)
    y_food = random.randint(0, 585)


class Segment(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ Class to represent the segment of the snake. """
    # Methods
    # Constructer function
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        #Call the parents constructor
        super().__init__()

        #Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([segment_width, segment_height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)

        #Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

#Call this function so the Pygame library can initialize itself
pygame.init()

#Create an 800x600 size screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])

#Set the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

allspriteslist = pygame.sprite.Group()

#Create an initial snake
snake_segments = []
for i in range(snake_length):
    x = 250 - (segment_width + segment_margin) * i
    y = 30
    segment = Segment(x, y)
    snake_segments.append(segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
x_food = random.randint(0, 785)
y_food = random.randint(0, 585)

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        #Set the speed based on the key pressed
        #We want the speed to be enough that we move a full
        #Segment, plus the margin
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = (segment_width + segment_margin) * -1
                y_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = (segment_width + segment_margin)
                y_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                x_change = 0
                y_change = (segment_height + segment_margin) * -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                x_change = 0
                y_change = (segment_width + segment_margin)

            if y < y_food+30:
                if x > x_food and x < x_food+30 or x+20 > x_food and x+20<x_food+30:
                    print('yummy')



    #Get rid of last segment of the snake
    #.pop() command removes last item in list
    old_segment = snake_segments.pop()
    allspriteslist.remove(old_segment)

    #Figure out where new segment will be
    x = snake_segments[0].rect.x + x_change
    y = snake_segments[0].rect.y + y_change
    segment = Segment(x, y)

    #Insert new segment to the list
    snake_segments.insert(0, segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

    #Draw
    #Clear screen
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [x_food, y_food, 30, 30])

    allspriteslist.draw(screen)

    #Flip screen
    pygame.display.flip()

    #Pause
    clock.tick(5)

pygame.quit()
```

hope this helped, thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Now it works, just some small adjustment left to do :) Ty!

Answer (score 1):

how about using:

```
if snake_headx == foodx and snake_heady == foody:

    food_eated()
    snake_grow()
```

just a suggestion though

didnt read all ur code, just thought u might find it usefull.

actuely ive came to a solution, so basicly what you want is a square, and when the snake comes near that square something should happen?, well ive got a racegame that makes you crash when you hit a square car, so il just copy the code here:

```
if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
        if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx+thing_width or     x+car_width > thing_startx and x+car_width<thing_startx+thing_width:
            snake_eated()
            snake_grow()
```

this monitors the x and y of your car (or snake) and checks when the thing (or food) 's y is smaller than your car, then it checks the x's and alot of other things, and basicly it creates a big line all around your square that you cannot cross in your case you'd just need to add the rest, would this work?

Comment: I have tryed it now but sadly with no success. The square gets printed in the upper left corner (indicating that it does not get the coordinates, instead uses (0,0)) and become super slow. I do not know how I should do it.

Comment: Can you show a version of your code that tries to use the `Food` class? The code in the question doesn't even attempt to use it at all.

Comment: Yes I will update the class when I get home. I copied the code to another text file while working on it so I did not mess anything up and posted the wrong code here.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if x >= x_food && x <= x_food + 15 || y >= y_food && y <= y_food + 15:
> ```

Why do you `OR` these pairs of conditions? Don't all 4 tests have to be true at the same time?

```
if x >= x_food && x <= x_food + 15 && y >= y_food && y <= y_food + 15:
```

Comment: No they do not have to, the snake will come eather from direction x or y. So only one of them have to be true.

Comment: `&&` and `||` are not valid operators in Python. Use `and` and `or`. I do think you want `and` on all of the tests here though. It doesn't make any sense for the food to be eaten just because you're on the same row as it, even if you're far to the right or left. You need to be both on the same row and on the same column.

Comment: Yes I realized that this morning when I tested it out. Must have slipped my mind. About the || and && it was a mistake because I have coded alot i C recently. Ty for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Make your food a sprite with a simple filled rectangle as the image, and then use sprite collision `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()` to check if your snake collides with your food. Pygame will take care of the actual logic whether two rectangles overlap for you.

Also, since you are already using sprite groups, I suggest you write an update function for your snake segments which moves them instead of creating a new segment every turn. Then you can simply call `allspriteslist.update()` in your main game loop, which will call the update function for every snake segment.

Finally, you might want to have a look at the numerous [snake examples](http://pygame.org/tags/snake) on the pygame website.